# Can heroku automatically commit data changes to a GitHub repo? - git

Tags: git, heroku

I currently have a GitHub repo (a private one, at the moment) with a discord bot within it, which actively uses aiosqlite to store some data within a database; I'm pretty new to Heroku, and I heard that Heroku actually erases all data acquired during runtime (like database files) every 24 hours when the worker is reinitialized - and I was wondering if there was a way to remedy this?

The first thing that came to mind was to have Heroku somehow automatically update the GitHub repo whenever data is updated during runtime; would that be possible? If so, how so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you mean when pushing  changes to Heroku you want to update Github repository OR link Github repository with Heroku?

Comment: "and I was wondering if there was a way to remedy this"- well the easiest and best way is to not use Heroku. There are pleanty of cheap server hosts starting at 5$ per month.

Comment: @puncher, a much better solution is to use a proper database.